# A simple Erlang twister

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I was playing with the lists in erlang. I have a randomly populated list of the following format:

```
List=[{10,"English",id1},{20,"Maths",id2},{30,"Geo",id3},{20,"English",id4}]
```

this is in the format [{Marks,Subject,Id}].

I wanted to make a list out of this list containing of only "English" as the subject which I did as follows

`NewList=lists:filter(fun(A)->element(2,A)=="English",List)`

which gives me

```
[{10,"English",id1},{20,"English",id4}]
```

which is fine but now I want to get the id of the tuple inside the NewList which has the greater value of the Marks for example, here,

out of `id1` and `id4` since id4 is greater, I need Id4.

The problem here is that List is the randomly populated list which means that in future all the 4 entries may be present whose subject is English only

Can anybody suggest a way out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After filtering the list, couldn't you use `lists:max/1` to get the tuple with maximum marks?

```
lists:max(NewList)
```

Comment: lists:max/1 will give me the maximum marks but I want to get the Id of the person having maximum marks

Comment: `lists:max` will give you the whole tuple. I have tried `lists:max` on the whole lists (without filtering) and it returns: `{30,"Geo",id3}`

Comment: yes you were right, lists:max/1 takes the first element of the tuple and uses it to find the maximum.I tried with changed order of tuple as [{subject,marks,id}], and got the tuple with maths as a subject as the maximum.

Comment: @abhishekranjan: No, `lists:max/1` doesn't take the first element of the tuple and uses it to find the maximum. See [Erlang Term Comparisons](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81100). For example `lists:sort([{1,b,2}, {1,a,2}, {1,d}]).` _Tuples are ordered by size, two tuples with the same size are compared element by element._

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, that would work:

```
NewList = lists:filter(fun(A)->element(2,A)=="English" end,List).
{_, _, MaxID} = lists:max(NewList).
```

Comment: Understood, list:max/1 takes the first element for comparison in a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Derek Brown's [lists:foldl()](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:foldl#foldl/3) solution will work correctly.  `lists:foldl()` allows you to step through a list while maintaining and manipulating a separate variable. After the last element has been processed, `lists:foldl()` returns the separate variable.  In this case, you can use the separate variable to update the Student with the highest mark.

You provide `lists:foldl()` with a fun whose arguments are the current element in the list and the separate variable that you want to manipulate.  The return value of the fun is the new value for the separate variable.

```
max_mark(Students, Subject) ->
    lists:foldl(
      fun({M,S,_Id}=Student, {Highest,_,_}) when S=:=Subject, M>Highest -> Student;
         (_Student, BestStudent) -> BestStudent
      end,
      {0, Subject, none},  %Starting value for the separate variable
      Students   %The list you want to step through
    ).
```

In your case, the separate variable will hold the student with the highest mark so far.

In the shell:

```
50> c(my).                           
{ok,my}

51> Students = [{10,"English",id1},{20,"Maths",id2},{30,"Geo",id3},{30,"Maths",id1},{30,"English",id4},{20,"English",id3}].
[{10,"English",id1},
 {20,"Maths",id2},
 {30,"Geo",id3},
 {30,"Maths",id1},
 {30,"English",id4},
 {20,"English",id3}]

52> my:max_mark(Students, "English").                                                                                      
{30,"English",id4}

53> my:max_mark(Students, "Maths").                                                                                        
{30,"Maths",id1}

54> my:max_mark(Students, "Geo").                                                                                          
{30,"Geo",id3}
```

Getting ties will take some more work.

The advantage of using `lists:foldl()` is that you only have to traverse your list once to get the information you want, rather than traversing the list one time with `filter()` and then a second time with `max()`.  You can imagine that if you had a list with millions of elements, it would behoove you to traverse the list as few times as possible.

Comment: Edited my answer to account for multiple entries with the same Marks - good point.

Comment: @DerekBrown, The op wants to select the highest score based on subject--not the highest score overall.  A knock on effect is that you can't use the first element in the list as the initial Acc value because it might not be the correct subject.

Comment: I know, but the OP already filtered on the desired Subject, as I mention in the first paragraph in my edited answer. Alternatively, could use the raw list and add that check in the code, as you did, and could then use an initial accumulator of the atom undefined, or some other flag value, and add a fun clause accounting for that possibility (if current Subject is the desired one, and the the acc is the flag value, return a new accumulator of {N, [This]} (using my variable names)).

Comment: @DerekBrown,  *I know, but the OP already filtered on the desired Subject* -- The whole reason you use foldl/foldr is so that you don't have to traverse the list more than once!  Also, your example in fact uses different subjects: a, b, c, d, e.

Comment: Understood, and as I said, the Subject check can be added if don't want to filter first. OP asked how to get the answer they want, given that they already have it filtered, so this does that. I used a,b,c,etc. as dummy values because they don't matter for what I'm showing. This isn't production code, but showing different options. The OP can use it as desired. /me washes hands of this posting

Answer (score 0):

Note that this assumes that the input list contains only tuples for the Subject desired, as the OP has already filtered on that. Alternatively that filter could be added here to avoid that separate step.

To get the tuples with the max value of an arbitrary element of each one (Marks in this case, of which could be more than one with the same Marks), without concern for tuple ordering rules, could do something like this (which does use the first element for comparison, as in this question), as long as the list contains at least one element.

Uses a tuple containing the value of the Marks for the first list entry, and that entry, as the initial accumulator. Then, starting with the second tuple, add to the list in the accumulator if the input tuple in question has Marks equal to the current highest. If the current input tuple has marks higher than the current highest, replace the list in the accumulator with a new list containing only the current input tuple. Else, keep accumulator as-is. If the list only contains one entry, it will be returned, by virtue of being the initial accumulator in the `foldl` call.

```
find_max([{FirstMarks, _, _} = First | T]) ->
  lists:foldl(
    fun
      %% Current tuple from input list has marks higher than current highest in accumulator,
      %%   so reset the accumulator to this new value for marks and new list containing
      %%   just this input list tuple
      ({N, _, _} = This, {MaxN, _L}) when N > MaxN ->
        {N, [This]};
      %% Current tuple from input list has marks equal to current highest in accumulator,
      %%   so add this input list tuple to the accumulator's list
      ({N, _, _} = This, {N, L}) ->
        {N, [This | L]};
      %% Current tuple from input list has marks less than current highest in accumulator,
      %%   so don't change accumulator
      (_,  Acc) ->
        Acc
    end,
    %% Accumulator is tuple containing initial high value for marks, and list containing
    %%   containing the first element of the input list
    {FirstMarks, [First]}, T).

1> tst_so:find_max([{30, a, a}]).
{30,[{30,a,a}]}
2> 
2> tst_so:find_max([{30, a, a}, {20, b, b}, {40, c, c}, {10, d, d}, {40, e, e}]).
{40,[{40,e,e},{40,c,c}]}
3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1> List = [{10,"maths", "Joe"},{12,"english","Mark"},{10,"maths","Rebecca"},{15,"english","Janice"}].
[{10,"maths","Joe"},
 {12,"english","Mark"},
 {10,"maths","Rebecca"},
 {15,"english","Janice"}]
2> Best = fun(List,Subject) -> lists:foldl(fun({Mark,S,Id},{BestMark,_}) when Mark > BestMark, S == Subject -> {Mark,[Id]};                      
2>                                            ({Mark,S,Id},{BestMark,Students}) when Mark == BestMark, S == Subject  -> {BestMark,[Id|Students]};
2>                                            (_,Acc) -> Acc                                                                                           
2>                                         end,{0,[]},List) end.                                                                                 
#Fun<erl_eval.12.52032458>
3> Best(List,"maths").                                                                                                                                 
{10,["Rebecca","Joe"]}
4> Best(List,"english").                                                                                                                               
{15,["Janice"]}
5> Best(List,"art").    
{0,[]}
6>
```